# Codeigniter Message: Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given -- stmt_send_long_data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, blob

I am using codeigniter and the following code has worked for a very long time until my server was updated to PHP 5.4.  My requirement is to allow for large uploaded files and the save them in a mysql database as a blob.  I can't store the link reference so that is not an option.

Below is my code.  The error I am getting is

```
Message: Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given
```

From the looks of things I am passing everything by reference.

Any help would be great.

```
function UploadFile($filepath, $contenttype, $fileext, $filename, $filesize)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->call_function('stmt_init',$this->db->conn_id);
    if($this->db->call_function('stmt_prepare',$stmt, 'INSERT INTO THE_TABLE (user_id, upload_description, upload, content_type, file_ext, file_name, file_size) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)')) 
    {
        $clientId = $this->input->post('clientid');
        $desc = $this->input->post('uploaddescription');
        $userfile = $this->input->post('userfile');

        $param = 2;
        $chunkSize = 8192;

        $this->db->call_function('stmt_bind_param',$stmt, "isbssss", $clientId, $desc, $userfile, $contenttype, $fileext, $filename, $filesize);

        if ($fp = @fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'r')) 
        {
            while (!feof($fp)) 
            {

                $this->db->call_function('stmt_send_long_data',$stmt, $param, fread($fp,  $chunkSize));

            }
            fclose($fp);
        }

        $result_query = $this->db->call_function('stmt_execute', $stmt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer.

Codeigniters function $this->db->call_function passes the values by value and not by reference.  I removed this function call and called bind params directly and it worked.